# why foreground garbage collection doesn't collect when a GC is triggered?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, clr

Below is a screenshot from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/background-gc

[image]

we know that background garbage collection is performed on one or more dedicated threads, depending on whether it's workstation or server GC, and applies only to generation 2 collections. and  foreground garbage collection does generation 0 and 1 collections

my questions in regards to the picture are:

Q1. the red arrow in thread 1, what does "init GC" mean? I feel like it means thread 1 triggers a GC, but if this is the case, why GC thread 1 and GC thread 2 don't do foreground garbage collection at this window? why dedicated GC threads are not collecting when appication thread 1, 2, 3 are suspended?

Q2. What makes thread 1, 2, 3 suspended again? I feel likt it i the background thread 1, 2 doing generation 2 collection and suspends thread 1, 2, 3 to sweep heap objects, but why those background threads are still collecting after thread 1, 2, 3 are resumed (you can see that the red BGC Thread timestamp is longer than the blue suspended timestamp of thread 1, 2, 3)

Comment: If you want the nitty-gritty, it's usually better to refer to the github docs, e.g. [https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/garbage-collection.md](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/coreclr/botr/garbage-collection.md). You'll notice that it often runs *some* code first to determine what actions to take and it may as well use the current thread it's on (that is otherwise going to be blocked) rather than attempting any cross-thread communication

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever hi could you have a look at this GC question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705363/how-to-use-weak-gchandle-to-monitor-a-object-is-collected-after-a-garbage-collec

Comment: I'll try to say it kindly: If you think the GC is not behaving correctly, you're almost always wrong. But people also often get the idea of GC wrong. 1) The GC is not required to reclaim memory eagerly, and 2) The GC is not required to reclaim all unreachable objects. Almost always, people seeking into GC internals are ignoring memory leaks in their own code which are better discovered using profiling tools than assuming core runtime features are broken or need assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q2:

> or BGCs there are 2 durations since each BGC will pause twice – one is the initial pause and the 2nd one is at the end of the mark phase (described in the GC event sequence section in mem-doc).

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/the-updated-getgcmemoryinfo-api-in-net-5-0-and-how-it-can-help-you/

Comment: could you have a look at this GC question please? thank you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705363/how-to-use-weak-gchandle-to-monitor-a-object-is-collected-after-a-garbage-collec

Comment: @whoisit sorry, I don't know :(